# Грамотно ли будет сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика

Если любви у меня не бывает в гостях.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Вряд ли подходит *родительный падеж*: если "любовь" персонифицирована, то о **гостях** так не говорят (обычно *именительный* падеж - "**она** не бывает у меня **в гостях**"); если же "любовь" в абстрактном смысле, то такой падеж вызывает вопрос о количественной мере несчётного существительного (вроде жидкисти или сыпучего продукта), в то время как "гость" - понятие *дискретное*, штучное. Поэтому и стилистически такое предложение звучит противоречиво, не по-русски. Для поэтического текста с его вольностями оно тоже не подходит: такое одностишие неритмично (ср. "**Коли любовь ко мне не ходит в гости**").

Answer (score 1):

Лучше сказать: **Если любовь у меня не бывает в гостях.**

**Пояснение**

1) Был в гостях у кого-л.  ― это был чьим-то гостем. В этом случае "был в гостях" является **составным именным сказуемым.**

2) Но "в гостях" может быть и  **обстоятельством,** например: У него в гостях не бывает скучно. Это безличное предложение, здесь "не бывает скучно"  также составное именное сказуемое.

**Приведенный пример не кажется корректным,** так как  смысл его не понимается ясно и однозначно: **"Если любви  у меня не бывает в гостях".**

В безличном предложении падежная форма   "в гостях" может восприниматься как обстоятельство (где?), а любовь может быть понята не как гостья, а как психологический настрой среди гостей.

Answer (score 0):

Вполне грамотно. Правда, не совсем ясно, что вы хотели сказать.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, так говорить можно, но это разговорный стиль. Вот подобные примеры:

1. Из Нац. корпуса:

― Где же она, по-вашему, служит? Ночью ее не бывает, днем заявляется. На «мерсе» катается… [Дарья Донцова. Уха из золотой рыбки (2004)] .

2. "По ночам ее не бывает дома" (песня)

Comment: А "_её_ не бывает _в гостях_" там тоже есть? "Её нет (->не бывает) дома" - нормально, выражение же "её нет в гостях" требует какого-то странного повода.

Comment: Нет, но чем отличается "не бывает дома" от "не бывает в гостях"?

Comment: Выше оставил пояснение: трудно представить себе ситуацию для такого выражения - выяснял, не в гостях ли она, и всякий раз в гостях её не было? "Среди гостей её нет" в порядке вещей, а "в гостях её нет" - иное.

Comment: Я вижу так: "Она у меня не появляется в качестве гости" -> "Ее не бывает у меня в гостях".